# select multi element using Agility Pack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am new to html agility pack

this is html source

```
<div>
  <h1>h1 content</h1>
  <h2>h2 content</h2>
  <p>p content</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>h1 content</h1>
  <h2>h2 content</h2>
  <p>p content</p>
</div>
```

and I use this code

```
Dim Web As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
Dim document As HtmlDocument = Web.Load("C:\temp\test.htm")
 For Each nod As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/h1")
    Response.Write(nod.InnerHtml & "<br>")
Next
```

to get these outputs.

```
h1 content
h1 content
```

How can I change the code to get such an output?

```
h1 content
p content

h1 content
p content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a different XPath expression.

```
Dim htmlSnippet = "
<div>
<h1>h1 content</h1>
<h2>h2 content</h2>
<p>p content</p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>h1 content</h1>
<h2>h2 content</h2>
<p>p content</p>
</div>"

Dim parser = New HtmlDocument
parser.LoadHtml(htmlSnippet)
For Each node In parser.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
        "//div/*[self::h1 or self::p]"
        )
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml)
Next
```

See [this documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths) for more examples.